# Docusign: display pre-filled tabs to all parties (Not just assigned)

Tags: docusignapi

I am currently pre-populating a bunch of tabs for 3 different parties (Buyer, Seller, and Agent). I would love to display these pre-populated fields to all parties (not just the ones assigned to the tab) as it may be concerning for the buyer to sign the contract if they can't even see what the agent has written.

I tried making each tab include a param of locked: true but that did not fix anything. I've also tried to manually make each field read-only but that also did nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful for us and for you if you explain what you've already tried (screenshots for example) and show us a sample of your code.

Comment: I don't believe this needs codes or screen shots. I just want to display the tab values I set for each templateRole between all roles (Rather than only showing it to the templateRole assigned).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are prepopulating values using API, then you can make it visible to all Signers by enabling one setting at the account level. You need to `Go To Admin -> SIGNING AND SENDING -> Sending Settings -> select "When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients"` checkbox under `"Fields and Properties"` section.